# Android parallax header effect

Tags: android, mono, parallax

I want to recreate UI features such as the new G+ app, or the airbnb interface where the parallax effect is invoked solemnly on the header picture.
My app uses (both) ListView and Gridview under different constraints, I was going over @CFlex [tutorial](http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/10/04/making-that-google-plus-profile-screen/#comment-1167222784) for recreating it but couldn't achieve the effect.

Main.axml:

```
namespace ParallaxTest
{
[Activity(Label = "ParallaxTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class ParallaxTest : Activity, AbsListView.IOnScrollListener
{
    int count = 1;

    public GridView _gridView;
    public CustomImageView _imageView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        _gridView = new GridView(this)
        {
            VerticalFadingEdgeEnabled = false,
            LayoutParameters =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent),
            CacheColorHint = Color.Transparent,
        };
        _gridView.SetOnScrollListener(this);
        _gridView.Adapter = new GridViewAdapter();
        _gridView.VerticalFadingEdgeEnabled = false;
        _gridView.SetColumnWidth(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / 2);
        _gridView.SetNumColumns(2);
        _gridView.SetVerticalSpacing(2);
        _gridView.SetHorizontalSpacing(2);
        _gridView.StretchMode = StretchMode.NoStretch;
        _gridView.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
        _gridView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Pink);
        _gridView.SetOnScrollListener(this);
        _imageView = new CustomImageView(this)
        {
            LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 400, GravityFlags.Center)
        };
        _imageView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
        FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.top_picture).AddView(_imageView);
        FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.items).AddView(_gridView);


    }

    public void OnScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
    {
        if (visibleItemCount == 0) return;
        if (firstVisibleItem != 0) return;
        _imageView.SetCurrentTranslation(_gridView.GetChildAt(0).Top);
    }

    public void OnScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, ScrollState scrollState)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class CustomImageView : ImageView
{
    protected CustomImageView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
    }

    public int mCurrentTranslation;

    public void SetCurrentTranslation(int currentTranslation) {
        mCurrentTranslation = currentTranslation;
        Invalidate();
    }

    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.Save();
        canvas.Translate(0, -mCurrentTranslation/2);
        base.Draw(canvas);
        canvas.Restore();
    }

}
```

}

Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#000000"
          android:id="@+id/items">
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/top_picture"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:background="#ffffff"/>
```

The app is running on mono powered by Xamarin's framework.
Any help's appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made an open source library that dose just what you need - https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll you can see the example here - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nirhart.parallaxscrollexample

Comment: Hello nr hope you are doing well.The scroll_one_parralax is not working if i place a linear layout below an imageview

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do parallax with a header is the next:

-Use ObservableScrollView that contains inside an ImageView that is your header image.
-Afterwards, on your java code of the activity that uses this layout, manage the ScrollView behaviour, by implementing ScrollViewCallBacks. And finally, to achieve the parallax effect, use imageView.setTranslation, like next:

```
scrollView.setScrollViewCallbacks(new ObservableScrollViewCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged(int i, boolean b, boolean b1) {
            imageView.setTranslationY(i*0.5f);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDownMotionEvent() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState scrollState) {

        }
    });
```

Pay special attention to  the attribute "i" that is the value of the scrolling movement. And use 0.5f or more to reach the proper effect during scrolling time. Hope it helps